# XML schema: Are such tags as <xsd:element>, <xsd:attirbute> built-in tags, part of the schema standard?

Tags: xsd

In the code snippet below, I have a question about such names as , `<xsd:element ...>, <xsd:complexType ...>.` Where are those names declared? I follow the URI http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema -> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd, and can't find their declarations. I'm curious as to whether they're "keywords" that need to be supported by every parser. I'm new to XML and obviously lack of some basic info to understand this. Please explain. Thank you.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
     Purchase order schema for Example.com.
     Copyright 2000 Example.com. All rights reserved.
    </xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>

  <xsd:element name="purchaseOrder" type="PurchaseOrderType"/>

  <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
```

Comment: they are defined in the xsd, `<xs:complexType name="complexType" abstract="true">...` and `<xs:complexType name="element" abstract="true">...` are right there

Comment: Viruzzo, thank you for pointing out that their definitions are in fact in http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd. I see them now. Gave up a little bit too early; will do a better search next time.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned by Jukka, the XML Schema specification can be found on w3c site. See the following URL for all XML Schema recommendations  http://www.w3.org/TR/#tr_XML_Schema

The URL you tried to reach ( http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema ) is not supposed to be active. It's only an identifier of the XML Schema dialect, dialect that includes the element you mentionned (complexType, element...).

The `xs:` or `xsd:` before the element name is called a "prefix" and is a reference to an identifier URI that is defined by `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` or `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`. Regularly, those namespace declarations appears only in the root element.

Comment: Vincent, thank you for the additional pointers and insight. The link http://www.w3.org/TR/#tr_XML_Schema is an eye-opener for me.

Answer (score 0):

Elements like the ones you mention are defined in the [XML Schema specification, part 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/).